# open a new tab when clicking a link button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below code to generate buttons with link. but problem is it is opening in same tab. i want it  to open in new tab. Can somebody suggest me a method which will work for most of the browsers.

```
<form>
   <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Home Page"
    onclick="window.location.href='http://www.wherever.com'"> 
</form>
```

Also kindly suggest if we have any better method to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is javascript you need to use like this:

```
<form>
   <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Home Page"
    onclick="window.open('http://www.wherever.com');"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it in a new tab, you have to set the target to _blank (as that it the target for a new tab).

> ```
> <form>
>    <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Home Page"
>     onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank')"> 
> </form>
> ```